# Converting a Collection<T> to a List<T>

Tags: java, java-8

Given a `Collection` of type `T`, what is the Java 8 idiomatic way to convert it to a `List` of type `T`? Is it the following?:

```
Collection<Foo> f;
f.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why would you want to do it anyway? Do you want some performance guarantee on how elements are added/removed? Both are interfaces, but believe you should not assume what you're about to convert is really a list.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski What you're about to convert *doesn't* have to be a List; the result will definitely be one, though. And reasons you'd want to do this include a) needing to make guarantees about the order of items in the collection, b) needing to call a method that requires a List without casting when you don't know for sure what kind of Collection you have, and c) needing a specific type of List for some reason.

Comment: Thanks! All points are valid and make sense.

Answer (score 11):

That will work properly. However, the idiomatic way from previous versions of java is still simpler and perfectly understandable.

```
Collection<Foo> f;
new ArrayList<>(f);
```